# How to calculate score of a doc in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a solr core named **Search Stats** with fields

```
query
search_count
number_of_clicks
added_to_cart
order_placed
```

I want a scoring function so that I can boost the docs according to the data.

This data is actually want to use for showing suggestions.
I have already used the sort function. suggest me some boost function other than sorting.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the same in Solr that you want to retrieve the score of every document using `q=colour Plus&fl=*,score`

Read more on this in below link

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_see_the_relevancy_scores_for_search_results

Lucene/Solr, provides TF-IDF (VSM based) scoring strategy.

The below link highlights more about TF and other terms

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-search-relevancy.html

Answer (score 0):

There are three boost methods you can use: boost, bf, and bq. Nicely laid out [here](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/#comments). The boost function can be used generally, and the bf and bq are specific to edismax and dismax. See the solr wiki [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ?highlight=%28boost%29#index-time_boosts) and [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax?highlight=%28boost%29#bq_.28Boost_Query.29). There are also index-time boosts, as described in the first wiki link above.